# C# string "likeness" comparison test

Tags: c#, string, testing

Are there any libraries out there that make it easy to compare the "likeness" of 2 strings in C#?  What I am thinking is if you have the strings,

```
"This is a test" // 100%
"THIS IS A TEST" // 95%
"    This is a test" // 98%
"This is" // 60%
"Foobar" // 0%
"this test is a" // 70%
```

etc.  They would each be given a score compared to a base string.

Comment: define likeness ... a bit more specifically, the general approach is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: That Levenshtein distance sounds interesting.  I put "likeness" in quotes because I am not sure how to define it!  It will be a matter of testing each method to see which has the best strike rate for my situation.

Comment: @mrnye, I am not sure what is the purpose of finding "likeness" but if it is for "sounds like" kind of use then you can find few implementation on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/soundex.asp

Comment: @VinayC It will be used primarily to match names which may be retrieved from different sources in slightly different format.  e.g., "Joe smoe" might possibly come in as "J.SMOE", "JOE.S", "J SMOE".  When reading these strings, it is clear they all mean the same person.  I would like to perform that same test programmatically to match up entries.

Comment: @mrnye, IMO, the best bet would be first divide the string into sub parts (first name, last name) based on known naming patterns and then try "likeness" test. BTW, here's one commercial lib: http://www.shuffletext.com/Highlight/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Levenstein.

> The Levenshtein distance is the difference between two strings. I use it in a web crawler application to compare the new and old versions of a web page. If it has changed enough, I update it in my database.

CodeProject has an implementation of this at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Levenshtein.aspx.